# Angular Ionic application deployed to Firebase not able to reach outside host APIs

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on my first Angular Ionic project with Firebase. I am working alongside a backend developer that is creating REST APIs with Firebase using Java. The frontend Angular code is currently deployed to firebase using firebase-tools CLI and the backend is deployed on the Google cloud on appspot.com. On my localhost I have no problem calling the API endpoints but when the frontend application is deployed, the HTTP calls are all failing. I suspect it has to be CORS issue because the codebase are on different hosts? When opening network tools the calls themselves are not returning any response code or body, simply saying failed as screenshot below. Moreover, when I go to the details the URL is the correct one and when I copy and paste it on my browser it is working fine. Need help to understand what the issue is. Can I make API calls to external APIs outside of my firebase host?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is highly likely that CORS has blocked the request. You have 2 options.

If you have server administrative privileges, or can make a request to whomever is, you can configure the server to accept those requests.

In PHP for example, you would set the following header at the beginning of the page which handles the requests:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Or, you can try using the [native http plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http) on the client instead of using angular's default httpClient, wherever you make calls to your API.

Comment: In the Angular code I am including this header along with others when making the http calls but it didn't solve the issue. I think what's happening is since the javascript is being hosted on the firebase host, we need to configure it there somehow. What I have tried next is create a firebase function using CLI tool and it is being hosted on cloudfunction.net. I have wrapped that function using Express and this call is now reachable through the javascript but now I have to figure out a way to proxy this call to the host where the api services reside on appspot.com. Still trying to figure it out

Comment: Yes the header needs to be set server side. If you are using firebase, i believe it is possible, there are just a few additional hoops ... have a look at these instructions via google ... these settings apply to firebase hosting as well: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors

Comment: thanks for your help I'll go ahead and read the docs!! I appreciate it

Comment: Id appreciate you marking the answer as correct when you have a chance.